# Uploading an image and save to SQL database in visual web developer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, vwdexpress

I have made a store procedure in database for adding an image, but now the problem is, I need to get the image data on client side and convert into bytes to insert to database, Here is my code i'm using:

```
     public static void AddImg (string asImgName, string asFilePath, string asUser, string asRemarks)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertImage", SqlConnect.con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = asImgName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = File.ReadAllBytes(asFilePath);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Uploader", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = asUser;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Remarks", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = asRemarks;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UploadDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Now I'm facing a problem:
On line 5 of the code 
`"cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = File.ReadAllBytes(asFilePath);"`
It only reads the server side path, so what changes do I need to make so that I can upload the image?

Thanks

======================================
I solved this problem by using the upload file control in VWD

```
fileUpload1.FileBytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reading the byte array before setting up the command?

```
public static void AddImg (string asImgName, string asFilePath, string asUser, string asRemarks)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(asFilePath);
    ...
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = bytes;
    ...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I'm assuming the client is the one calling the method above. Not positive this will solve your problem, but it's worth a shot. Reading the bytes before-hand is easier to read anyway and you should make this change.

Comment: this doesn't work also, but i solved this problem using the upload file control in VWD